# Send data from one class to a different class

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to use a value of a textbox inside an other UIViewcontroller class.
First, I instantiate the RegistrationViewController class inside the LoginViewController class.

```
RegistrationViewController registration = new RegistrationViewController();
```

Then I save the value inside the public Email variable.

```
registration.Email = txtEmail.Text;
```

My RegistrationViewController class looks like that:

```
    public partial class RegistrationViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public String Email { get; set; }
    }
```

If I use the email variable, I don't get anything as a result.
I can't see anything, that could be missing. Could it be because, I use a partial class?

**Update**

This is basically how I use it.

```
 public partial class RegistrationViewController : UIViewController
        {
            public String Email { get; set; }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();
            txtEmail2.Text = Email;

        }
}
```

Comment: It could be, because txtEmail.Text is smpty or null

Comment: I already tested that. If I output the value of registration.Email inside the LoginViewController Class I get a value.

Comment: How do you use Email variable in RegistrationViewController ?

Comment: You might be better of making a static class with properties that should be kept for a long time: `public static class Stuff { public static string Email; }` and then use `Stuff.Email` from both Controller classes.

Comment: I use it to set the text for a UITextfield text. So it looks like that: txtEmail2.Text = Email;

Comment: Can you share code how did you use Email in RegistrationViewController

Comment: @IkramTurgunbaev I updated the post with the code i use in Registration

Answer (score 0):

As [Here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad) said `ViewDidLoad` calls after the `controller's view` is loaded into `memory`. So while `ViewDidLoad` calls `Email` not assigned yet. Place `txtEmail2.Text = Email;` to another `method` or `event` and then call it

Comment: So I wrote a method inside the Registration class, which I call before the Registration view controller is pushed. Now I get the value inside the variable but I get an new error: object reference not set to an instance of an object. How can I get it to work in the viewDidLoad?